# Python Iterate Over Every Row of A Spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

[image]

I wrote a function that would breakdown each timestamp and calculate the number of minutes in between Down and Up times. I haven't been able to get this to iterate for every row.

```
data1 = str(list(data['Adjusted_Down']))
data2 = str(list(data['Adjusted_Up']))
breakdown(data1, data2)
```

Code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('E:\Savers\Python\Python3 - Master\lab.xlsx')

def breakdown(x, y):
    string1 = x.split()
    variable1 = string1[0]
    dateVariable = variable1.split('-')
    variable2 = string1[1]
    dateVariable2 = variable2.split(':')
    hour = int(dateVariable2[0])
    minute = int(dateVariable2[1])
    seconds = int(dateVariable2[2])

    string1B = y.split()
    variable1B = string1B[0]
    dateVariableB = variable1B.split('-')
    variable2B = string1B[1]
    dateVariable2B = variable2B.split(':')
    hourB = int(dateVariable2B[0])
    minuteB = int(dateVariable2B[1])
    secondsB = int(dateVariable2B[2])

    if hourB > hour:
        sumMinutes = (hourB - hour)*60
        sumMinutes = sumMinutes + (minuteB - minute)
        print(sumMinutes)
    elif hourB == hour:
        sumMinutes = (minuteB - minute)
        print(sumMinutes)
```

Comment: your function is very inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you wanted to run breakdown() function for each row in the data df

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    data1 = str(row['Adjusted_Down'])
    data2 = str(row['Adjusted_Up'])
    breakdown(data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but if you are wondering how to get the time delta, then I would suggest that when reading the spreadsheet, you use the [parse_dates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#datetime-handling) parameter.

```
data = pd.read_excel('E:\Savers\Python\Python3 - Master\lab.xlsx', parse_dates=['Adjusted_Down', 'Adjusted_Up'])
```

At that point, you can simply subtract the 2 columns and then convert to the desired unit.

Answer (score 1):

First load the columns as datetime as @samuel mention above,its much faster to load the file like this.

```
data = pd.read_excel('E:\Savers\Python\Python3 - Master\lab.xlsx', parse_dates=['Adjusted_Down', 'Adjusted_Up'])
#Then you can calculate the timedelta as easy as
data['timedelta-minutes'] = data.Adjusted_Up - data.Adjusted_Down

#convert to minutes
data['timedelta-minutes']  = data['timedelta-minutes'].dt.minute
```